# How to solve this x^2+13^x=z^2 in C# help please

Tags: c#

x ^ 2 + 13 ^ x = z ^ 2

I try this but I don't know how to do next step to show this values

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (Math.Pow(i, 2) + Math.Pow(13, i) == Math.Pow(i, 2))
}
```

I need this now. Thanks to all of you for your time and help.

Comment: What is x? What is z? What do you mean by "solve"? Do you want do calculate x from z or z from x or plot the graph of this function?

Comment: You may find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: I guess you need a list of x and z's  which satisfy this equation. Is it?

Comment: I need to  verify if the numers from 0 to 100 is equal to that Z and show on console the result  I insert the code in the body of description

Comment: What you are checking is if `x^2 + 13^x = x^2` and that will never be true for any number.

Comment: Even formular on (Math.Pow(i, 2) + Math.Pow(13, i) == Math.Pow(i, 2)) is nonsense.
x^2 + 13^x = x^2 cannot be true cuz 13^x cannot be zero.

Comment: if you wish to use 2 variable on there, use i and j for forloop

Comment: x^2+13^x=z^2 this is the formula I need to solve it and I try to loop it @Arphile

Comment: @IonTimus: You need two loops: One for `x` and one for `z`.

Comment: There´s not much too **solve** here as you did´nt provide what x and z actually is. I guess you want a nested loop iterating from zero to 100 for **both**, `x` and `z`. But you only provide a single loop for `x`. Please have a lopp at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: ok I try it thank for help guys:)

Comment: @IonTimus Are you really need to solve x^2 + 13^x = z^2 instead of x^2 + 13^y = z^2?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

first of all,

this looks not so good... 
Use it like this

```
int x = 2;
int y = 13;
int z = 2;
int whatever, anotherWhatever;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    whatever = Math.Pow(i, x) + Math.Pow(y, i);
    anotherWhatever = Math.Pow(i, z);

    if (whatever == anotherWhatever)
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```